# Mercurial: Add branch from master repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I have a forked project, and now the master repository has added a new branch which I want on my forked project.

Is it best practice to add the branch locally and then merge from the master repository, or is there a more correct way of doing this?

My guess is this, but I don't want to mess things up:

```
hg branch theNewBranch
hg pull -r theNewBranch ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/master_repository/theproject
hg merge 0011223344ff
hg commit -m "Merged in master repository branch"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to add it locally.  Every commit has the branch it is on *burned* into it.  If they have a commit on `theNewBranch` you'll get it.

If you want everything they have mirrored locally just do:

```
hg pull ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/master_repository/theproject
```

And if you want to merge in into your local branch do:

```
hg checkout mylocalbranch
hg merge theNewBranch
```

Comment: Got it - so if I want to merge into a branch of the same name, then I just create a branch with the same name, and just merge into that branch, and it will contain everything from the pull.

Comment: If you don't already have a branch of the same name, you just do `hg pull` and you're done -- it will be created locally.  If you already have it then you precede the pull with the `hg checkout theNewBranch` and follow it with a `hg merge`, which by default will merge in the "other" head of whatever branch you have checked out.